# Newton-euler dynamics equations simplification

Tags: equation-solving

I have 6 equation and i need to simplify them. I can simplify this equations easily in my draft but i need a code for simplify more complicated system in this way. My code is:

```
ClearAll[Fx10, Fy10, Fx12, Fy12, x1, y1, x2, y2, t, T1, T2, m1, m2, I1, I2, L1, L2, θ1, θ2, eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6,eqns]


eq1 = -Fx10[t] - Fx12[t] == m1*x1''[t];
eq2 = +Fy10[t] - Fy12[t] - m1*g == m1*y1''[t];
eq3 = +T1[t] - T2[t] + (Fx10[t] - Fx12[t])*L1/2*Cos[θ1[t]] - (Fy10[t] + Fy12[t])*L1/2*Sin[θ1[t]] ==I1*θ1''[t];

eq4 = +Fx12[t] == m2*x2''[t];
eq5 = +Fy12[t] - m2*g == m2*y2''[t];
eq6 = +T2[t] - Fx12[t]*L2/2*Cos[θ1[t] + θ2[t]] - Fy12[t]*L2/2*Sin[θ1[t] + θ2[t]] == I2*(θ1''[t] + θ2''[t]);

eqns = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6};

(*   Code for finding  Fx10,Fy10,Fx12,Fy12   *)
{Fx10[t], Fy10[t], Fx12[t], Fy12[t]} = Solve[eqns, {Fx10[t], Fy10[t], Fx1[t], Fy12[t]}]

(*   Code for finding  Deq1,Deq2             *)
{Deq1, Deq2} = Eliminate[eqns, {Fx10[t], Fy10[t], Fx12[t], Fy12[t]}]
```

every 3 equations have one governing differential equation(Deq). I need to find this 2 governing equations and 4 unknown. I do it in my draft like this picture:
[image]

I can do it on paper but i need to write a code for more complex system that can't be solved with hand on a paper! eliminate can find 2 governing equations correctly and i need just put every differential equations in Deq1 and Deq2 automatically after eliminate But solve cant find 4 unknown. Please help me to find my desire answer. I sent correct answer with a picture, i need to a code for  gathering this output automatically with Mathematica.

Comment: This seems a refinement of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166243/nsolve-or-solve-of-newton-euler-equations-system-for-use-in-inverse-dynamics - yes?

Comment: it is a part of that question. but they are a bit different. i simplify and remove some part of that question and add some more challenge. but i think they are two different sample that every one can complete the other. This question is more promising to solve but it is not all thing that i need.